# Exporting a dataframe to several csv files based on value in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I have the following code for exporting each "id" to a separate csv file. Each csv file should be named as an id. Here in my case, we should have three different csv files named 23, 24, and 25. I have the code in below but it gives me an error. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd

path = "users/AR/csv files"

for (id), id in df.groupby(['id']):
     group.to_csv(f'{id}.csv', directory=path, index=False)
```

```
NameError: name 'group' is not defined
```

| id | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 2/2/2016 | 24 |
| 24 | 2/4/2016 | 56 |
| 25 | 2/3/2016 | 135 |
| 23 | 3/4/2016 | 46 |
| 24 | 3/8/2016 | 176 |
| 25 | 3/9/2016 | 23 |
| 23 | 3/16/2016 | 98 |
| 24 | 3/13/2016 | 114 |
| 25 | 3/17/2016 | 43 |

I am expecting three separated csv files in the directory.

Comment: Your loop is using `(id), id`, use `id, group` instead? :)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs has it right. You should do `for id, group in df.groupby(['id']):`. Have you tried it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney Thank you for your comment. Sorry I was away from my computer. Yes it does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
for (id), id in df.groupby(['id']):
```

with:

```
for id, group in df.groupby(['id']):
```

When iterating groupby object, you get separate grouping value (in `id`, in your case), from particular group sub-dataframe (here: in `group`). `id` is then used to name a csv file, while `group` df is exported to csv.

Furthermore, there is no `directory` parameter in `to_csv` method. The easiest method is to include path in the filename string, like `f'users/AR/csv files/{id}.csv'`. If you need OS-agnostic solution, you can use `os.path` method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7745170/oliver Thank you for your code. The only problem with this code is removing the id column in the csv output file. How can I keep the id column in the output? Of course, it is a column with the repeated values of the id

Comment: But, the id column is present! Are you sure your code is exactly the same as mine? Try confirming with print:
```
for id, group in df.groupby(['id']):
    print(group);
    group.to_csv(f'{id}.csv', index=False)
```
id column should be the first one (after index column). In csv there is no index column, so id should be the first one.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with list comps:

```
dfs = [x.reset_index(drop=True) for _, x in df.groupby("id")]
[x.to_csv(f"users/AR/csv files/{x['id'][0]}.csv", index=False) for x in dfs]
```